# Make text field readonly

Tags: sitecore-client, permissions, editor-user-permissions

Is there any easier way of creating read-only fields for all users except admin, not by setting permissions on every user or by creating a role and assigning it to every user/group?

Comment: Have you tried assign the security permissions on sitecore\Everyone ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Modifying raw security values

1. Open the Content Editor
2. Locate the item that represents the template field
3. On the View tab in the Ribbon, make sure the following checkboxes are checked:

   - Standard fields
   - Raw values
4. Go to the Security section
5. Insert the following text into the Security field:

   ```
   ar|sitecore\Everyone|pe|-field:write|
   ```
6. Save the item.

[image: Security setting]

This will make the field read-only for all Sitecore users except the administrators. This is because Sitecore administrators can *always* edit all fields, regardless of security.

Note: if you want this to apply to users in all domains, use the following value:

```
ar|Everyone|pe|-field:write|pd|-field:write|
```

---

## Using the Security Editor

You can also deny access to this field via the Security Editor UI. Just make sure that the "Field Write" column is shown by checking it in the Columns dialog in the Security Editor.

[image]

Comment: I would slightly modify this answer to break inheritence instead of explicitly denying Field Write to the role sitecore\Everyone:  **ar|sitecore\Everyone|pe|+field:read|!*|pd|+field:read|!*|** .This way you can (if the need arises) grant Field Write back to members of a specific role without having to give them full admin.

Comment: @NickAllen I tried to recreate your code but it isn't working for me. Hope I made some mistake. Please help me I tried lots of option but nothing helps. I like to restrict write access for all user but except users with a particular role. It would be really helpful if you have any solution on this.